# Can REST API deal with transction critical application?

Tags: architecture

There was Q&A for REST API whether it was needed for next generation of transaction critical applications. One of answer was not required to bring extra burden around 9 years ago. Is it the same situation ? Or Is REST API more effective and generally accepted ?

Comment: More effective and generally accepted than what?

Comment: network may fail, as a consequence you cannot span a transaction across network calls

Answer (score 0):

REST APIs are very generally accepted, and is commonly used for VERY critical applications.  Everything from medical devices to banking systems are using them.  Like any application, it has to be designed properly, and your transaction handling has to be thought out carefully, but it is not any different than any other architectural style.

More often than not, you want your transactions to be first-class citizens, such that if you were having a banking app, you would wrap your credit and debit transactions in a single call, allowing a true 2-phase commit to occur.  This approach lets you relax transactionality for bits of the application that are not transactional (which are more than you would first think).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually my question was about MSA. REST API can handle these mission critical service such as 2-phase commit. But MSA has a silo data persistent to deal with these possible inconsistency issue. How about your opinion ?

Comment: What does MSA stand for?  I'm unfamiliar with that acronym.  Also, "silo data persistent" doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

MSA : Micro Service Architecture For refactoring, we are considering to use REST API for Micro Service Architecture to apply "Silo Data Persistent". I knew that MSA might not need to apply entirely for certain mission critical enterprise applications. I want to hear some opinion or trend how popularly applying MSA to mission critical enterprise applications.